# Задача на Пайтон

Tags: python, python-3.x

Нужно написать код который будет проверять введенный текст и проверять палиндром ли это и выводить на экран "это палиндром" или "это не палиндром".
вот я пробовал делать код но у меня постоянно показывает что это палиндром:

```
s = input("введите текст")
l = len(s)
for i in range(1//2):
    if s[i] != s[-1-i]:
        print("это не палиндром")
        quit()
print("палиндром")
```

Comment: Можно сделать проще `'palindrome' if s == s[::-1] else 'common word'`.

Comment: Можешь вписать это в мой код

Comment: Там  l или 1 написан?)

Comment: там написано L l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x = input("Введите слово: ")
y = list(x)
k = y[::-1]
if y == k:
  print("Это палиндром")
else: 
  print("Это не палиндром")
```

Можно попробовать через список.